# Display number of files found and progress

Tags: python

I currently have a code that searches for files by keyword. Is there a way to show the number of files found, as the code runs and or show the progress? I have a large directory to search and would like to see the progress if possible. The code I currently have doesn't show much info or processing time.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import sys

def update_progress_bar():
  print '\b.',
  sys.stdout.flush()

print 'Starting ',
sys.stdout.flush()

path = '//server/users/'
keyword = 'monthly report'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for name in files:
     if keyword in name.lower():
        time.sleep(0)
        update_progress_bar()

print ' Done!'
```

Comment: you might as well do `sys.stdout.write('.')` instead of `print '\b.',` so you don't end up printing the space in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple, but why not just keep a counter?

```
files_found = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for name in files:
     if keyword in name.lower():
        files_found += 1
        time.sleep(0)
        update_progress_bar()

print "Found {}".format(files_found)
```

---

Edit: if you want to calculate progress you should first figure out how many files you'll be iterating over. If you use a nested list comprehension you can flatten each of the `files` from each triple emitted by `os.walk`.

```
filenames = [name for file in [files for _, _, files in os.walk(path)]]
num_files = float(len(filenames))
```

Now at each step you can describe the progress as being the current step number divided by the number of files. In other words, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the step number:

```
files_found = 0
for step, name in enumerate(filenames):
  progress = step / num_files
  print "{}% complete".format(progress * 100)
    if keyword in name.lower():
      files_found += 1
      time.sleep(0)
      update_progress_bar()
```

If you want to get more creative in how you print the progress that's a different question.

Comment: Is there a way to show the percentage of completion?

Comment: That's a bit meatier of a question but I can answer that, give me a sec.